# Powershell export nested object arrays into CSV

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

When i look into my object arra and type a $obj[2] (as exam) I'm getting

```
Name      : audit_event
UUID      : c6479a6f-f1bd-4759-9881-fcb493821aff
Timestamp : 17-06-20 13:30:48 +00:00
Fields    : {[audit_schema_version, 1], [event_time, 17-06-20 13:30:48 +00:00], [sequence_number, 1], [action_id, 541934402]...}
Actions   : {}
```

I would like to get all fields into a single csv file.

So first I started to find at least the fields, but dispite some solutions I saw i'm not getting it OK.

```
foreach ($UUID in $logsOBJECT[2].UUID) {
  echo $UUID
  foreach ($field in $logsOBJECT.$UUID.Keys) {
    echo $field
    }
  }
```

This doesn't work.
I'm not a Powershell developer so quite novice.

I have to use Powershell because Synaps Analytics doesn't give a better option to read and process its logfiles.

Kind regards, Harry

Comment: Or export to json instead.

Answer (score 0):

Given an object that looks like this in JSON:

```
[{
    "Name": "audit_event",
    "UUID": "c6479a6f-f1bd-4759-9881-fcb493821aff",
    "Timestamp": "17-06-20 13:30:48 +00:00",
    "Fields": [["audit_schema_version", 1], ["event_time", "17-06-20 13:30:48 +00:00"], ["sequence_number", 1], ["action_id", 541934402]],
    "Actions": {}
}]
```

(You can generate that by using `$obj | ConvertTo-Json` so it's easier for others to reproduce)

First we loop through the `$obj` list by passing it to `ForEach-Object`, or `%` for short. For each element we create a `$result` object that contains all the data, except the `Fields` property.

Then we loop through the fields property on the object. Each field is itself a list, where the first (0) element is the name, and the second (1) is the value. For each field, we add a property to the `$result` object with the name and value of the field.

When this is done we return the `$result` object to the pipeline, and that gets passed to `Export-Csv` which writes it to a file.

```bsh
$obj | % {
    $result = $_ | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty Fields

    $_.Fields | % {
        $result | Add-Member -Name $_[0] -Value $_[1] -MemberType NoteProperty
    }
    return $result
} | Export-Csv -Path C:\test.csv -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your exact PS module of SynapsAnalystics...

But it seems to be a problem accessing nested arrays in Powershell.

Here I have an example with Windows services:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $servic[20] | fl


Name                : BrokerInfrastructure
DisplayName         : Background Tasks Infrastructure Service
Status              : Running
DependentServices   : {workfolderssvc, WMPNetworkSvc, WSearch, embeddedmode}
ServicesDependedOn  : {DcomLaunch, RpcSs, RpcEptMapper}
CanPauseAndContinue : False
CanShutdown         : False
CanStop             : False
ServiceType         : Win32ShareProcess
```

Here, if I want the output of **$servic.DependentServices** I need to know the Keys\Propertys of $servic.DependentServices. ie,

You can get that by :

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $servic[20].DependentServices

Status   Name               DisplayName                           
------   ----               -----------                           
Stopped  workfolderssvc     Work Folders                          
Running  WMPNetworkSvc      Windows Media Player Network Sharin...
Running  WSearch            Windows Search                        
Stopped  embeddedmode       Embedded Mode
```

So the Propertys here are

```
Status   Name               DisplayName etc...
```

**$servic[20].DependentServices** would be similar to **$obj[2].Fields** in your case.
Try and see the Keys or Property's within $obj[2].Fields then decide which Property you want to loop through.

you can get that with

```
$obj[2].Fields | get-Module (this will give all parameters)
```

Then you can loop through the required Properties, like in my case:

```
foreach ($echserv in $servic[0-2])
    {
        write-host "*****************Service******************"
        echo $echserv.Name
        Write-Host "####DependentServices####"
        foreach ($echDependServic in $servic.DependentServices.DisplayName)
            {

                echo $echDependServic
            }
    }
```

which would give output:

```
*****************Service******************
XboxGipSvc
####DependentServices####
Smartlocker Filter Driver
Agent Activation Runtime_ea2d3
Agent Activation Runtime
Windows Audio
Agent Activation Runtime_ea2d3
Agent Activation Runtime
Xbox Live Networking Service
.
.
.
```

Hope this helps with your problem.

PS: There are better ways to display your output using [hashtables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7) in Powershell. This can later be used to export to CSV etc..